# amcharts_Child tree should not open untill clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, amcharts, amcharts4

How to make child trees open on click? When we click the parent node A it opens its all child and sub-child trees.

It should open the sub-child on click. Like when click on A, it should not open A21 which is sub-child of A2.

[image: amchart]

JS Code is following

```
/**
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 */

am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

// Create chart
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4plugins_forceDirected.ForceDirectedTree);

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4plugins_forceDirected.ForceDirectedSeries());

// Set data
series.data = [{"name": "A",
  "children": [{
    "name": "A1",
    "value": 1,
  }, {
    "name": "A2","value": 1,
    "children": [{
    "name": "A21",
    "value": 1,
  }]
  }, 
               {
    "name": "A3",
    "value": 1,
    }]
}];

// Set up data fields
series.dataFields.value = "value";
series.dataFields.name = "name";
series.dataFields.id = "id";
series.dataFields.children = "children";
series.dataFields.linkWith = "link";
// Add labels
series.nodes.template.label.text = "{name}";
series.nodes.template.label.valign = "center";
series.nodes.template.label.fill=am4core.color("#000");
series.nodes.template.label.dy = 10;
series.fontSize = 12;
series.minRadius = 30;
series.maxRadius = 30;

// Configure circles
series.nodes.template.circle.fillOpacity = 0.5;
```

HTML Scripts

```
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/dataviz.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/plugins/forceDirected.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the to disable expand all function

```
var nodeTemplate = networkSeries.nodes.template;
nodeTemplate.expandAll = false;
```